# Count specific patterns in data frame, doing interpolation in R

Tags: r, dataframe, interpolation

I have a dataset in data frame format, like this:

```
wpt    ID   Fuel  Express   Local
 1     S36   12      0         1
 2     S36   14      1         0
 inter S36   NA      1         0
 inter S36   NA      1         0
 3     S36   16      1         0
 inter S36   NA      0         1
 4     S36   18      1         0
 5     S36   22      1         0
 6     W09   45      0         1
 inter W09   NA      1         0
 7     W09   48      0         1
```

I'd like to treat the subdata dat[c(2,inter,inter,3),] (**any part with "inter" combined with regular numbered wpt**) as a unit.

(1) count how many such sub-units in my data frame, in this case it has two (unit with row from 2 to 3, and 3 to 4)

(2) then count how many such units with **Express or Local value consistent from the starting to ending value of the sub-unit**. In this case, it has 1 such unit consistent (**row 2 to 3, it's all Express**) and 1 unit different (**row 3 to 4, start and end with Express, inter is Local**) from the starting or ending value of such units.

(3) all the calculations are by ID.

The expected output is like this:

```
ID   consistent    total
S36      1            2
W09      0            1
```

(4) what if I want to **interpolate the missing values** in Fuel column? Doing simple linear interpolation. Like the first two NAs be replaced by 14.66667 and 15.33333, which come from:

```
seq(14, 16, length.out=3)
```

The expected out put like this:

```
wpt    ID   Fuel    Express   Local
 1     S36   12        0         1
 2     S36   14        1         0
 inter S36   14.66667  1         0
 inter S36   15.33333  1         0
 3     S36   16        1         0
 inter S36   17        0         1
 4     S36   18        1         0
 5     S36   22        1         0
 6     W09   45        0         1
 inter W09   45.75     1         0
 inter W09   46.50     1         0
 inter W09   47.25     1         0
 7     W09   48        0         1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Jimbou, I've no idea right now..

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: @akrun, please see the updated post

Comment: @akrun, plz share some idea, i'm thinking all night without progress.

Comment: @WhiteBig Your description of case (2) doesn't mention that you need the results by `ID` as shown in the expected output. Is this also required for case (1) or do you need just the plain total count?

Comment: @UweBlock, I updated the post, need by  ID. My bad.

Comment: Hi all. What if I want to interpolate the missing values in Fuel column? Like the first two NAs be replaced by 14.6667 and 15.3333, which is a linear interpolation from seq(14,16,length.out=4)?

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in a single post.  It is better to post that as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

```
subs <- with(rle(df$wpt),{
    ends <- cumsum(lengths);
    n <- grepl('^[0-9]+$',values);
    w <- which(head(n,-2L) & values[-c(1L,length(n))]=='inter' & tail(n,-2L));
    data.frame(start=c(0L,ends)[w]+1L,end=ends[w+2L]);
});
subs$ID <- df$ID[subs$start];
subs$consistent <- mapply(function(s,e,eq) all(eq[s:e]),subs$start,subs$end-1L,MoreArgs=list(diff(df$Express)==0L));
subs;
##   start end  ID consistent
## 1     2   5 S36       TRUE
## 2     5   7 S36      FALSE
## 3     9  11 W09      FALSE
res <- aggregate(cbind(consistent,total=rep(1L,length(ID)))~ID,subs,sum);
res;
##    ID consistent total
## 1 S36          1     2
## 2 W09          0     1
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(wpt=c('1','2','inter','inter','3','inter','4','5','6','inter','7'),ID=c(
'S36','S36','S36','S36','S36','S36','S36','S36','W09','W09','W09'),Fuel=c(12L,14L,NA,NA,16L,
NA,18L,22L,45L,NA,48L),Express=c(0L,1L,1L,1L,1L,0L,1L,1L,0L,1L,0L),Local=c(1L,0L,0L,0L,0L,1L,
0L,0L,1L,0L,1L),stringsAsFactors=F);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I need to look into the code. I really don't have a sense of this situation.

Comment: @WhiteBig For the calculation of `subs` you can also try `a <- which(d$wpt == "inter");
before_inter <- (a-1)[c(TRUE,diff(a-1,1)>1)];
after_inter <- (a+1)[c(diff(a+1,1)>1,TRUE)];subs <- data.frame(start=before_inter,end=after_inter)`

Comment: @Jimbou,what if I want to interpolate the missing values in Fuel column? Like the first two NAs replaced by seq(14,16,length.out=4)[2,3] = 14.66667 and 15.33333

Comment: @WhiteBig not sure what you mean. Is this a completely new question? You can try `d$Fuel[is.na(d$Fuel)] <- unlist(apply(subs, 1, function(x, y) seq(y$Fuel[x[1]], y$Fuel[x[2]], length.out=x[2]-x[1]+1)[seq(1, length(x[1]:x[2]))[-c(1, length(x[1]:x[2]))]], d))

`

Answer (score 1):

If I got your intentions right, my suggestion for case (1) using `data.table` and `rle` is

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("
       wpt    ID   Fuel  Express   Local
        1     S36   12      0         1
        2     S36   14      1         0
        inter S36   NA      1         0
        inter S36   NA      1         0
        3     S36   16      1         0
        inter S36   NA      0         1
        4     S36   18      1         0
        5     S36   22      1         0
        6     W09   45      0         1
        inter W09   NA      1         0
        7     W09   48      0         1")
rdt <- dt[, rle(wpt), by = ID]
rdt[values == "inter" & lengths >= 1, .(total = .N), by = ID]
```

which results in

```
    ID total
1: S36     2
2: W09     1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this is not the output i expected. Anyway, will look into the new functions i haven't met before.

Comment: `lengths >= 1` will always be true for a run-length encoding object.

Comment: Just tried to get case (1) right before adding complexity.

Comment: @bgoldst You're right. My first impression was that OP was after the `"inter", "inter"` sequence. Therefore, I had a check on `lengths >= 2` included.

Comment: Thank you for your input, what if I want to interpolated the missing values in Fuel column? Like the first two NAs be replaced by 14.6667 and 15.3333, which come from seq(14,16,length.out=40)??

Answer (score 1):

To count patterns you can use `rle`. For instance:

```
x <- rle(df$wpt == 'inter')
y <- which(x$values)
cumsum(x$lengths)[y - 1L] + 1L          # run starts
#[1]  3  6 10
x$lengths[y]                            # run lengths
#[1] 2 1 1
subunits <- lapply(y, function(i)
    seq(cumsum(x$lengths)[i - 1L], length.out=x$lengths[i] + 2L))
```

now `subunits` is a list of row indices

```
subunits
#[[1]]
#[1] 2 3 4 5
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 5 6 7
#
#[[3]]
#[1]  9 10 11
```

but to interpolate missing values none of this is really necessary, instead you can do

```
nas <- is.na(df$Fuel)
df$Fuel[nas] <- approx(seq(nrow(df)), df$Fuel, xout=which(nas))$y
df
#     wpt  ID     Fuel Express Local
#1      1 S36 12.00000       0     1
#2      2 S36 14.00000       1     0
#3  inter S36 14.66667       1     0
#4  inter S36 15.33333       1     0
#5      3 S36 16.00000       1     0
#6  inter S36 17.00000       0     1
#7      4 S36 18.00000       1     0
#8      5 S36 22.00000       1     0
#9      6 W09 45.00000       0     1
#10 inter W09 46.50000       1     0
#11     7 W09 48.00000       0     1
```